# I want to sort a dictionary inside a list by number

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I need to sort a ranking of points by descending order. The users and points are inside `lista_ranking` which includes de following code

```
[{'partido': {'codigo': 'AAA', 'fecha': datetime.date(2022, 11, 20), 'hora': '13:00hs', 'equipo_local': 'Catar', 'equipo_visitante': 'Ecuador', 'estado': 'Finalizado', 'goles_local': 0, 'goles_visitante': 1}, 'usuario': {'cedula': '123', 'nombre': 'Juan', 'apellido': 'Hardoy', 'fecha': '(2003, 3, 12)', 'puntaje': 0}, 'goles_local': 1, 'goles_visitante': 0}, {'partido': {'codigo': 'AAA', 'fecha': datetime.date(2022, 11, 20), 'hora': '13:00hs', 'equipo_local': 'Catar', 'equipo_visitante': 'Ecuador', 'estado': 'Finalizado', 'goles_local': 0, 'goles_visitante': 1}, 'usuario': {'cedula': '1234', 'nombre': 'Santi', 'apellido': 'Stev', 'fecha': '(2003, 3, 12)', 'puntaje': 8}, 'goles_local': 0, 'goles_visitante': 1}]
```

I want to print a ranking for the most points to the least with the `nombre`(name) and `apellido`(surname) + the `puntaje`(points).

I tried the following but it is not working

```
for numeros in lista_ranking:
        sorted(str(numeros['usuario']['puntaje']))
        
        print(numeros["usuario"]["nombre"], numeros["usuario"]["apellido"], str(numeros["usuario"]["puntaje"]),"pts")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will order tuples of points, first name and last name from highest to lowest;

```
sorted([(d['usuario']['puntaje'], d['usuario']['nombre'], d['usuario']['apellido']) for d in lista_ranking], reverse=True)
```

Comment: With the code 
`ranking_high_to_low=sorted([(numeros['usuario']['puntaje'], numeros['usuario']['nombre'], numeros['usuario']['apellido']) for numeros in lista_ranking], reverse=True)`

`print(ranking_high_to_low)` 
it prints the ranking from highest to lowest like this: `[(8, 'George', 'Stev'), (5, 'Gon', 'Henderson'), (0, 'Kai', 'Potts')]`.
Which `for` should I use in order for it to print one below another?
Thank u very much for your help!

Comment: Easiest way is probably `print('\n'.join((f'{p} - {n} {a}' for p,n,a in ranking_high_to_low)))`